# How does statsmodels calculate in-sample predictions in AR models?

Tags: time-series, python, predictive-models, autoregressive, statsmodels

I am very new to time series modeling and statsmodels and trying to understand the AR model in statsmodels. Suppose I have a data record `y` of 1000 samples, and I fit an AR (1) model on `y`. Then I generate the in-sample prediction from this model as `y_pred`. I do this as

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg
model = AutoReg(y,1).fit()
y_pred = model.predict()
```

I get the parameters of the model using `model.params`.

I would like to know, after estimating the model parameters, how does statsmodels calculate the in-sample predictions? For ex. how is `y_pred[10]` calculated?

I am sorry if the question is too basic, thanks for the help.

Comment: Same question was asked in stackoverflow and has been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67236144/how-does-statsmodels-calculate-in-sample-predictions-in-ar-models/67258872#67258872

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness I'm posting the answer given on Stackoverflow by @AlexK which the OP says has answered their question:

---

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model):

> The autoregressive model specifies that the output variable depends linearly on its own previous values and on a stochastic term (an imperfectly predictable term).

In your model example, you have one predictor - lagged value of `y`. In this simple case, the `.predict()` method multiplies each lagged value by the value of the estimated linear slope parameter for that predictor and adds the estimated value of the intercept of that line. So `y_pred[10]` will be equal to the product of the fitted slope parameter and `y[9]`, with the value of the intercept estimate added.

Here is an example:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg

y = [1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 9, 1]

model = AutoReg(y,1).fit()
model.params
# array([ 5.72953737, -0.49466192])
```

The first value in the `params` array is the estimated intercept parameter and the second value is the estimated linear (slope) parameter.

```
y_pred = model.predict()
y_pred
# array([5.23487544, 4.74021352, 4.2455516 , 2.76156584, 4.74021352, 1.27758007])
```

The first value in the `y_pred` array is the predicted value for the second value in the `y` array.  It is calculated as:

```
-0.49466192 * 1 + 5.72953737 = 5.23487544
```

The second value in the `y_pred` array is computed as:

```
-0.49466192 * 2 + 5.72953737 = 4.74021353
```

and so on...